# How to make stage selector in Action Script 3 Adobe Flash

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm still newbie in flash game programming (AIR). I want to ask how to make stage selector that move from 1 point to another point. After finish stage 1 stage 2 button become available to press and it's highlight. Since i can't post any picture to tell exactly what i want.
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2iljz7s.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Why exactly can't you post a picture?

Comment: This is a really broad question. There are tons of ways this could be done, and your best route depends entirely on how your game currently works, which you haven't shown.

Comment: need more badge to post picture. Very sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron said it is a really broad question. To try and get you setup I would say Boolean's or in general just add and remove the Mouse Event Listeners.

However if you are trying to have it to where if the player unlocks these stages and have them start off on the stage they last played if they close the game, then you will have to add a save feature using the `sharedObject`

So if the player goes on to the next stage you can do something like this in your ENTER_FRAME event Listener:

```
if (stage_1Complete)
        {
            btn_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stage_2)
            btn_2.gotoAndStop("HIGHLIGHT");

            btn_1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stage_1)
            btn_1.gotoAndPlay("NOHIGHLIGHT");

        }
```

but as stated above it would be a lot easier to help if you have some type of code to show us of what you have tried so far.

Either way what i basically coded above is if you complete the first stage then add a listener to the second button and to have it highlighted all you need to do is create a frame label and name it something like HIGHLIGHT then have it go to that Frame Label. Then at the same time the stage 1 button will have the listeners removed and again create a frame label for that button then have it go to that label with no highlight that you create.

Hope this gives you some insight.